# How to fetch data from firebase realtime database in react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, fetch-api, use-effect

Need help as I want to fetch data from firebase database. I tried may approaches but failed in all of them.

In some cases the data was fetched instantly, but the get request was sent to the database every second, even though I added the right dependencies in the useEffect array of dependencies.

In another case the data was fetched, but then got blank as I reloaded the page. But it was working if I was switching the to another component and then coming back to it.

```
import { Grid, Paper } from '@material-ui/core';
import Topbar from '../Utilities/Topbar';

import './Statistics.css';
import database from '../../firebase';

const Statistics = () => {
    const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState([]);
    // const [fetchedPopularity, setFetchedPopularity] = useState([]);

    // var db = database.ref('Orders/')
    // let statData = [];
    // const fetchStats = async () => {
    //     db.on("value", snapshot => {
    //         // statData = [];

    //         snapshot.forEach(snap => {
    //             statData.push(snap.val());
    //         })
    //     })
    //     setFetchedData(statData);
    // }

    // const db1 = database.ref('Orders/Popularity');
    // let popData = [];
    // const fetchPopularity = async () =>{
    //     db1.on("child_added", snapshot => {
    //         snapshot.forEach(snap => {
    //             popData.push(snap.val());
    //         })
    //     })
    //     setFetchedPopularity(popData);
    // }

    // var db = database.ref('Orders/')
    // const statData = [];
    // db.on("value", snapshot => {
    //     // statData = [];

    //     snapshot.forEach(snap => {
    //         statData.push(snap.val());
    //     })
    // })
    // setFetchedData(statData);

    // child added
    // useEffect (() => {
    //     var db = database.ref('Orders/')
    //     let statData = [];
    //     const fetchStats = () => {
    //         db.on("child_added", function (data) {
    //             var subnode = [data.val()];
    //             var subnodeKey = data.key;
    //             console.log(subnode.Revenue);
    //         })
    //         // setFetchedData(statData);
    //     }
    //     fetchStats();
    // }, []);

    // useEffect (() => {
    //     var db = database.ref('Orders/')
    //     let statData = [];
    //     const fetchStats = () => {
    //         db.on("child_added", snapshot => {
    //             console.log("hello")
    //             // statData = [];

    //             snapshot.forEach(snap => {
    //                 statData.push(snap.val());
    //             })
    //         })
    //         setFetchedData(statData);
    //     }
    //     fetchStats();
    // }, []);

    // useEffect(()=>{
    //     fetchStats();
    //     fetchPopularity();

    // },[fetchStats, fetchPopularity]);

    // console.log(fetchedData);
    // console.log(fetchedData[2]);
    // console.log(fetchedPopularity);

    // const fetchStats = async () => {
    //     db.on("value", snapshot => {
    //         temp.push(snapshot.val());
    //         console.log("2");
    //     })
    // }
    let temp = [];
    var db = database.ref('Orders/');
    useEffect(() => {
        // console.log("1");
        // fetchStats();
        db.on("value", snapshot => {
            temp.push(snapshot.val());
            console.log("2");
        })
        setFetchedData(temp);

        // console.log("3");
    }, []);

    // function print() {

    //     fetchedData.map(data => {
    //         // data.Popularity,
    //         // data.Revenue,
    //         // data.TotalOrders,
    //         // data.UID
    //         console.log(data)
    //     });
    // }
    // print();
    console.log(fetchedData);
    return (
        <Grid container>

            <Topbar />

            <Grid container spacing={8}>

                <Grid item sm={12} md={7} >
                    <h2 className="home_heading">Hi Name Surname</h2>
                    <p className="home_text_alt">Welcome back</p>

                    <p className="home_text">Statistics</p>

                    <Grid container spacing={2}>
                        <Grid item sm={4}>
                            <div className="orders_1">
                                <h1>{fetchedData.TotalOrders}</h1>
                                <p>Total Orders</p>
                            </div>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item sm={4}>
                            <div className="orders_2">
                                <h1>40</h1>
                                <p>Most Ordered</p>
                            </div>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item sm={4}>
                            <div className="orders_3">
                                <h1>{fetchedData.Revenue}</h1>
                                <p>Total Revenue</p>
                            </div>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>

                    <Paper elevation={3} className="graph"></Paper>

                </Grid>

                <Grid item sm={12} md={4}>
                    <p className="home_text" style={{ marginBottom: "20px" }}>Popularity</p>

                    <Grid container spacing={4}>
                        <Grid item xs={10}>
                            <Grid container className="summary_name">
                                {/* <Paper elevation={2}></Paper> */}
                                <div className="summ_card_col"></div>
                                <p>TYPE A - Petri Dish</p>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={1}>
                            <div className="summary_count">
                                <p>4</p>
                            </div>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid container spacing={4}>
                        <Grid item xs={10}>
                            <Grid container className="summary_name">
                                {/* <Paper elevation={2}></Paper> */}
                                <div className="summ_card_col"></div>
                                <p>TYPE A - Petri Dish</p>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={1}>
                            <div className="summary_count">
                                <p>4</p>
                            </div>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid container spacing={4}>
                        <Grid item xs={10}>
                            <Grid container className="summary_name">
                                {/* <Paper elevation={2}></Paper> */}
                                <div className="summ_card_col"></div>
                                <p>TYPE A - Petri Dish</p>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={1}>
                            <div className="summary_count">
                                <p>4</p>
                            </div>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid container spacing={4}>
                        <Grid item xs={10}>
                            <Grid container className="summary_name">
                                {/* <Paper elevation={2}></Paper> */}
                                <div className="summ_card_col"></div>
                                <p>TYPE A - Petri Dish</p>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={1}>
                            <div className="summary_count">
                                <p>4</p>
                            </div>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid container spacing={4}>
                        <Grid item xs={10}>
                            <Grid container className="summary_name">
                                {/* <Paper elevation={2}></Paper> */}
                                <div className="summ_card_col"></div>
                                <p>TYPE A - Petri Dish</p>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={1}>
                            <div className="summary_count">
                                <p>4</p>
                            </div>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid container spacing={4}>
                        <Grid item xs={10}>
                            <Grid container className="summary_name">
                                {/* <Paper elevation={2}></Paper> */}
                                <div className="summ_card_col"></div>
                                <p>TYPE A - Petri Dish</p>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={1}>
                            <div className="summary_count">
                                <p>4</p>
                            </div>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid container spacing={4}>
                        <Grid item xs={10}>
                            <Grid container className="summary_name">
                                {/* <Paper elevation={2}></Paper> */}
                                <div className="summ_card_col"></div>
                                <p>TYPE A - Petri Dish</p>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={1}>
                            <div className="summary_count">
                                <p>4</p>
                            </div>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>

                </Grid>

            </Grid>
        </Grid>

    );
}

export default Statistics;
```

Comment: Please don't put multiple problems in one question. Instead, edit your question (there's a link right under it) to [include a single, minimal-but-complete fragment of code that you think should've worked](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show (e.g. through `console.log`) what unexpected behavior you got. A good guideline: aim for having a single snippet of code that shows up without scrollbars.